# Javascript - Get value of url of OpenLayers Vector Source

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have create a Vector source and specified a url for the source. What I want to do now is get the value of that url (in string) from somewhere else. Is that possible?

```
var sourceChitwan = new ol.source.Vector({
url: chitwanURL,
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

**chitwanURL** is a string containing the url.
I want the url from somewhere else. I tried **sourceChitwan.getUrl()** but it returns **undefined**.

Comment: I tried exactly the same as you and it works for me:`var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({url: "Hello World!", format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()});` and then `vectorSource.getUrl();` returns "Hello World!"

Comment: I don't know why it't not working for me. It returns 'undefined'. Will give it another try. Thank you @LidiaParrilla

Comment: Maybe your variable chitwanURL does not have the correct format. Just guessing the reason... Try substituting your line `url: chitwanURL,` by the real URL between quotes as I did.

Comment: I tried getUrl and I got an error saying it is not a function. I did try using the actual url in the url field. But the result is same. There is no problem with the variable and its initialization because the features gets loaded onto the map perfectly.

Comment: Can you show the exact lines of code that you are employing when you get that error?

Comment: `var chitwanURL = 'http://localhost:9090/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typeName=learning_Workspace:ChitwanFew&outputFormat=json';

var sourceChitwan = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: chitwanURL,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    // crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
});`
This is the initialization...
Now I used getUrl() just underneath it...

Comment: It works for me with openlayers v4.3.2. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using v3.14.2

Comment: That's the problem. As you can see in the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) of that version, the class ol.source.Vector does not have a method called getUrl. They added it later. So you need to update to a newer version

Comment: Worked like a charm. Should have looked at the documentation. Thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved but I will leave here the solution so anyone with a similar problem in the future can find it easily without reading all the comments:

Openlayers class `ol.source.Vector` does not have a method to get the URL in the API [version 3](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html). It is necessary to upload to [version 4](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getUrl) to find it.

Comment: Confirmed... Updated the OpenLayers API Version and worked.